# django orm, backward relations,

Tags: django-models

I have models as,

```
class Invoice():

class Entry():
   invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='entries')
   amount = CurrencyField()
```

I have to calculate total amount for a invoice by backward relation

Comment: A `CurrencyField` stores a currency, like `USD`, not an amount, so not `5 USD`, only `USD`...

Answer (score 1):

A [**`CurrencyField`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django-money/django-money/blob/3.0/djmoney/models/fields.py#L153-L165) stores a currency, like `'USD'`, not an amount of a given currency, so not <s>5 USD</s>. You need a `MoneyField` to do this.

The modeling thus should look like:

```
from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField


class Invoice(models.Model):
    pass


class Entry(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
        Invoice, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='entries'
    )
    amount = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
```

You can sum up the currency of an invoice with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

my_invoice.entries.aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))['total']
```

this will only work if the `amount`s all have the *same* currency.